# Base64 decoding of JSONObject in Android 2.1

Tags: android, json, arrays

I need to decode JSONObject in Android 2.1 with Base64.I know that Base64 class supports Android 2.2+,that's why I include the source code in my project.So I need to do something like that :

```
JSONObject clientHash = new JSONObject();
byte[] tmpSecData = Base64.decode(clientHash.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash"));
```

Any suggestions how to do that or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try it,

1. Convert the clientHash.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash") in String then byteArray,
2. then use,

   ```
   byte temp[];
   Base64 b = new Base64();
   String jsonString = clientHash.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash").toString();
   temp = b.decode(jsonString.getBytes());
   ```
3. then use your temp byte[].

Hope this will help you. If its work then inform me. Thanx.

Comment: Actually it seems ok for now.Just need to add 0 as flags in b.decode.

Comment: the last line should looks like this : temp = b.decode(jsonString.getBytes(),0);

Comment: Actually you are talking about this Base64 for android2.2  import android.util.Base64; and the code I give you is for import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; that's why. anyway your work is done. then its fine. Thanx. :-)